# Can we add TLS version 1.2 while using POSTMAN?

Tags: postman, tls1.2

I am not getting a response in my rest webservice as postman sends request via SSL . Can we change it to TLS ?

Comment: What? Can I ask you what you think is the difference between SSL and TLS?

Comment: I do not think it is possible to change the SSL version in Postman at this moment. Requests are always based on SSLv3 it seems: https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4677. Postman-team states no clear timeframe for this feature.

Comment: I was able to get the response using ARC -Advanced Rest Client. Its a chrome plugin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this can be done. It is the other way around, You disable protocols which you don't want to communicate with. So disable it in Postman.
please see the screenshot. My API only accepts TLS1.2 so I disabled all older version and I was able to fix this issue.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on setting >> Protocols disabled during handshake

as below picture

[image]